# Android Camera2Basic example: images are not saved

Tags: android, android-camera2

Im using the the [Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and running it on my phone. 
After taking a picture it says the picture has been saved in:

> /store/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files/pic.jpg

but there is not that file in that path.

**EDIT**: This is the directory in Ubuntu where I expect to find the file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryrjF.png)

Comment: so what problem you are facing . is there some kind of error after clicking image ?

Comment: Can you show some logs here ?

Comment: @Tej no error on the app

Comment: How did you check if the file was there? Does the directory exist?

Comment: @Passiondroid the logcat is empty

Comment: @greenapps the file is not there. Apart from that, I had to create the "files" directory (end of the path) but after that even the file is not inside of it.

Comment: Repeat: How did you check that? Does the directory exist?

Comment: @greenapps I have edited my question. That is the path where Im checking from Ubuntu if the file is saved or not.

Comment: `showToast("Saved: " + mFile);`. Strange place to call that toast. You should do that in the run() of ImageSaver().

Comment: For which Android version you are compiling project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot check if the file is created in a directory of your Android device if you do that from your PC.

Act normal by using a File Explorer app on your Android device.

You can only see that file with Ubuntu after rebooting your Android device.

Comment: yes, thanks, you are right. Could you explain me why this happens? I mean I don't understand why I have to reboot my device to see the files. And, yes I can see the files stored from a file explorer app installed in my device.

Comment: Because then the mediascanner will be started and will finally find your file. After that the MTP protocol can use that info to tell Ubuntu. If you do not want to reboot you should invoke the mediascanner yourself for the newly created file. Two code lines will do. You are #12345 who wonders about this feature. Code has been posted many times.

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission to manifest.It is missing there

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks, I have just added it, but the file is still not saved in `/store/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic/files/pic.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file path and it will work, try this

```
val folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + 
           "/Pictures/YourAppNameHere") 

    if (!folder.exists())
    {
        folder.mkdir()
    }
var filePath = folder.absolutePath
file = File(filePath, PIC_FILE_NAME)
```

Some phones has folder that is called Photos instead of Pictures, so check your phone first, or you can keep it to only "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()", and it will be saved in the file manager